# Sharepoint Services 3 Survey

Tags: sharepoint

Using Sharepoint Services 3 Surveys is there any way to remove a 'Choice' option from the answer list once it has been picked by a user?

I'd like to ensure that an option can only be chosen once.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Services OOB features allow you to set if multiple answers are allowed for the survey.